How long can a covered, indoor pool be winterized?
We have an indoor Endless Pool in our sunroom.  We winterized in in Dec (leaving about 1 ft of water to hold liner) and would have normally opened it in April but have not done so.  Now we will be leaving in September for 6 months so want to leave it winterized.  What should we do to ensure that no mold or mildew forms on the cover in our absence?

When you winterized it, did you add a biocide?

I'm no pool expert, but, depending on temperature, you may want to add some water to offset evaporation and prevent it from drying out completely in the 6 months you'll be gone.

I had not thought about evaporation...thanks, will add water and the winterizing chemical the pool service provided.
